# iTunesArtwork and XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to add the iTunesArtwork file to my iPhone application in order to follow the guidelines for icons/artwork for iTunes.  I've added a file that matches the iTunesArtwork requirements (512x512 JPG) to my project.  Once I do that, I can no longer install the application on my device.  I keep getting this error:

> Your mobile device has encountered an unexpected error (0xE8000058)
>
> iTunesArtworkCaptureFailed

Does anyone have any experience resolving this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the case of an ad hoc build, I've had some success doing the following:

- Create a 512x512 png of the icon/artwork you want to show up in iTunes.
- Rename the file to **iTunesArtwork** (with no extension and that capitalization) and
  place it in your app root folder and
  then add it at the top level of your application resources in xcode.
- Rebuild the app in release for the device version you are deploying to

I've had this work with ad hoc builds, but to be honest I took it out because it works when I do provisioned release builds and causes the error you show there when I do debug builds and try to run on the simulator.  It wasn't worth the hassle of adding and removing the file from the project for me.

Comment: yup, it was.  And I'm having the same behavior you described in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 15):

I'm pretty sure that file needs to be a .png not .jpg?

Try removing the file, doing a clean, then re adding the file as iTunesArtwork

BTW you don't need that file - it's just so that Adhoc distribution has the icon show up in iTunes - it's not needed for App Store apps. They get the icon from a combo of the 57x57 icon and the 512 image you upload to iTunesConnect.

Comment: both png and jpg file format are accepted. The iTunesArtwork file, however, has to be without extension.

Comment: @fifigyuri thanks I couldn't figure out the problem! It's weird how Apple specifies with no file extension.. but yeah. thanks a bunch

Comment: That's interesting, the AdHoc builds only require iTunesArtwork? Helpful tip. +1