# How to set up itunesartwork for ad-hoc distribution?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ad-hoc-distribution

We're effecting in-house testing, 
Everything is done, working, archiving.
But when we achieve the app, making an .ipa, we don't see itunes cover, even though we have an image named iTunesArtwork without extensions like .png. Also when our boss wants to install the .ipa with iTunes he doesn't have cover as well.
What do you think?
thanks

Comment: What happens if you have a file extension? What is the file format of the iTunesArtwork file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I achieved the app not with distribution profile, but with development,
Thanks,
Test Flight is great by the way

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the image is in png format and has dimensions of 512x512 pixels. Don't forget to add iTunesArtwork at the root of the resources folder of your bundle (add it to the Resources folder of your project in XCode). It should work. See also [iTunesArtwork and XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855707/itunesartwork-and-xcode)

Comment: I have a project with several targets (each with a different app icon). Any idea on how to setup different iTunesArtwork versions for each target? I can have each resource file belong to the corresponding target, but two files with the same name can't reside on the same directory...

Comment: For such situations I wrote a compile time script that overwrites the iTunesArtwork in the resource folder with the appropriate variant as a first step in the build process. The script can also access the build variables so you can define a custom user variable with the variant artwork name (per target) and use it in the script. Pay attention however not to mess up your version control with the permanently changing artwork file.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not fluent in build scripts... you don't happen to have sample code, do you?

Comment: I suggest you to open a separate question for this. Then maybe you could post here the URL of the question so I'll notice it.

Comment: There: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783064/multiple-versions-of-itunesartwork-in-one-project

Comment: Fine, I see that somebody came up already with a somewhat even cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Follow guidelines of these links its mater of 30 mins

http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3

Comment: "This site is currently in private mode. You must log in to continue. If you do not have an account, you will need to request an invite from the site owner."