# Multiple versions of iTunesArtwork in one project?

Tags: ios, xcode, adhoc, itunesartwork

I have a single Xcode project with several targets, each spitting out a different app with a different icon. The icons are in their target-specific resource folders so they don't collide.

But the 'iTunesArtwork' file (i.e., the icon used for display of Ad Hoc builds in iTunes) must be placed in a specific location (Project Root), and named exactly that, so multiple versions can't coexist.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be able to do the same trick with the Artworks file, store several files (with the same name) at different folders, add them to the project respecting the files `Target Membership` (File Inspector section).

They don't have to be in the project root. If there're several icon files at different project folders, each icon is a member of it's own target, then you have different target icons with the same icon name (and naturally the only icon file is copied to the bundle root).

You might need to have one of the icons at the project root folder (e.g. it might be copied there for you by Xcode), but during the build the icons should be copied from the folders referenced in the project rather than from the project's root folder.

[image]

Comment: I'll try this approach. What settings should I check when importing?(besides target membership) "Create groups for any added folders" (a.k.a yellow folder icon) or "Create folder references for any added folders"(a.k.a. blue folder icon)?

Comment: Is there any way to "Show Package Contents" of an .ipa, to check if it worked?

Comment: The folders and grouping is completely up to you, you'll probably want to create a folder&group pares per target to easily distinguish the resources. Just be careful not to replace the existing file from another target and you'll be fine anyway.

Comment: Forget that last one... I checked the contents of the .xarchive file (before exporting to .ipa) and iTunesArtwork is there... WITH THE PNG EXTENSION. Must fix that.

Comment: Sure, ipa is just a zip, rename it. You can remove the picture extension, no problem here. And the app is just a folder, use context menu to view it's content.

Comment: It turns out that hitting space on the file name in finder to edit and deleting the extension does not actually remove the extension... Just changes it to "Hidden". The only way to remove the file extension is in the File Info inspector! (and Finder prompts you for confirmation)

Comment: @NicolasMiari - How did you move iTunesArtwork file from a folder to root while building ?

Comment: I didn't. Resources added to the project as "folder references" (yellow icon) get copied to the root of the app bundle, regardless of the directory structure they occupy on your Mac.