# App icon not showing up in iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I built ipa file and then dragged that ipa file in iTunes.When I install that application on my device ,the app icon is showing in my device,but not showing up in itunes,like other application which are installed in my phone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add image having name iTunesArtwork to resources folder. Make sure to delete the .png extension of file

check this 
[iTunesArtwork and XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855707/itunesartwork-and-xcode)

Comment: what should be the dimension.The app is for ios7.1.

Comment: Who down voted this answer? It's correct. For AdHoc deployment you need the `iTunesArtwork` file for the icon to show up in iTunes.