# APP icons in iOS application | Artwork image

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, xcasset

I'm working on iOS application (iPhone, iPad) and little confused about the app icon stuff. I'm using XCAssets and my app supports **version>=8.3**. So,the image below shows what I've selected from XCAssets and I've placed all these images.

I've looked into multiple links on Google and SO but getting confused e.g this link [App icons iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html).

1. App icon for iTunes Connect. The above mentioned link states that we need to add Artwork icon for iTunes **(1024x1024)**, but i don't know where to add that. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283126/how-do-you-change-the-app-stores-large-icon-on-itunes-connect) answer, but probably it's outdated now as i can't see any such options on iTunes Connect
2. What are "**CarPlay**" icons for?
3. What is "**iOS icon is pre-rendered**"

Please answer the above mentioned points. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

.[image]

Comment: CarPlay: Is for version supporting CarPlay (iOS in the Car). The 1024*1024, in iTunes Connect, it's asked, else, in MyApp/App Store/Finalize (last menu on the left side), you can change it. The "pre-rendered" is for the glossy effect (not currently used in last version if I remember).

Comment: @Larme, thank you. but i can't locate this "finalize" menu on itunes connect. Right now, my app is not on sale and i submit it via testFlight for internal testing. (I've checked in MyApp/AppStore, yet there's no such thing as finalize or may be i'm unable to find that)

Comment: "Prepare for submission" if it was validated through TestFlight

Comment: no, but i don't have to submit it now. i just want to update the app icon. @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Artwork icon will be sent to Apple on the iTunes Connect site when you enter your application metadata for a release of your app.  You do not put it in the XCAssets.
2. CarPlay icons are if your app supports CarPlay, Apple's iOS interface for car infotainment systems.  Not needed if you app doesn't support CarPlay.
3. "iOS icon is pre-rendered" is a setting that will determine whther iOS addes a glare to the icon in iOS 6 and before.  It should have no effect on apps installed and run on iOS 7 or later.

Comment: Thanks. but for testflight builds as well, we can see app icon on itunes connect. isn't it the same (1024x1024)?

Comment: I thought you could just update the release metadata.  If that's not working, you could try including it in the archive: http://stackoverflow.com/a/856021/3708242

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Wottle's answer,
Answer to the artwork icon point: We have to add app icon on itunes connect. For that you need to go into your app and have to update it in AppVersion/AppIcon as shown in figure attached. then click on "Save".

[image]

Ofcourse, this method will change with time (As apple makes update in itunes UI often). Right now, it's the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, @Fayza Nawaz, for writing this. I was wondering for an hour how to set the large icon of an app record that is uploaded for testing (and still not submitted in the store) in itunesconnect. The process is nowhere near straightforward. Thanks again!

Comment: glad that it helped :)